# Has anyone else been unable to locate and install the GRASS plugin in QGIS 2.0.1?

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, qgis-plugins

After uploading and installing QGIS 2.0.1, I am unable to locate and install the GRASS plugin.  The plugin is not listed in the 'Plugin Manager'.  The 'Plugin_Installer' is also shown in red, indicating that there is a problem with the plugin.  Has anyone else experienced the same problem?  The look and feel of 2.0.1 is great though, and there are some nice new features.

Comment: What OS are you running?

Answer (score 2):

I dont have the same problem with the new 2.0.1 version. But I did have the problem with an older version (1.9 master). After deinstallation and reinstallation It worked fine.

Comment: Thanks, I did give this a try, but it unfortunately made no difference.

Comment: On Linux (at least Ubuntu) you have to make a **completed uninstall** to make this work.

Answer (score 1):

It may be the plugin has not been migrated to be usable with QGIS 2.0.1 thus it being in red

Answer (score 1):

I assume you have been using the stand-alone installer? Following the current discussions on the mailing list, there are some packaging issues with that installer. Try the OSGeo4W installer instead if you need GRASS.

The "Plugin installer" shown in red is another part of the packaging issues. It's an old version which is not needed in 2.0 and should not have been included in the installer.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with installer QGIS-OSGeo4W-2.0.1-2-Setup-x86.exe. I have re-installed it using QGIS-OSGeo4W-2.0.1-3-Setup-x86.exe and now the GRASS plugin is there.